# Would asking how to set up a fully-customizable MediaWiki-based website be appropriate for this Wiki?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

I'd like to ask how to set up a fully-customizable MediaWiki-based website (not by Wikia, but one where I can install any extension I want) for free, but I'm afraid this would be like a website recommendation-type question as it would involve people recommending which website to do this on.

Answer (score 1):

By "Wiki", do you mean the main Pro Webmasters site, or this Meta site?

Assuming that you meant the main site, then unfortunately I don't think this would be considered on-topic:  it sounds like it would fall under the [too broad](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) category, and like you suspected, it would probably result in [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which as you seem to already know, is off-topic here.

I'm not sure how many webmasters there are here using MediaWiki type websites, but you could ask your questions in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) room. Also, if you're looking for recommendations for software, you can try asking this over at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but it's wise to review their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) first to see what's considered on-topic for their site.

Thanks for asking though.

Comment: Yeah Pro site. It'd be website recommendation wouldn't it? As I'd be looking for a website to set up this fully-customizable MediaWiki site.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We generally mark these questions as duplicates of [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) catch-all question to avoid spam and self-promotional answers.